# C# - Get file names from remote directory (without anchors)

Tags: c#, html

I have been trying to get from our localhost/remote directory listing of all images on that folder.

What I so far tried follows (based on others SO's questions, but changed a bit to include these on my arr', but still using a WebRequest.):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(GetDirectoryListingRegexForUrl(url));
var arr = regex.Matches(photosName).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

public static string GetDirectoryListingRegexForUrl(string url)
{
    if (url.Equals("http://localhost:MyPort/MyNewbieProject/images/"))
    {
        return "<a href=\".*\">(?<name>.*)</a>";
    }
    throw new EverythingExplodedException();
}
```

So, as a result from that, I get something like:

```
"<a href=\"All-Your-Base-00.jpg\"> All-Your-Base-00.jpg</a>"
```

I wanted to get just the "All-Your-Base-00.jpg", so I could download it into my App and use it to fill my Image's.

How should I proceed? Should I manually trim this string, or there is a better way to do so?

Comment: Need a little more clarification of what you are trying to do.  My guess is that you are crawling a site and trying to find out which images in a directory are currently being used?

Comment: You can use something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx  Directory.GetFiles

Comment: Hey @JasonNesbitt, no. I'm getting all the images that are to be used in our application. As this folder is constantly updated, we add these images by code. I'm trying soon Jim Mischel answer, and will update if it worked or not.

Comment: @Ani Directory.GetFiles does not works with URL's and remote directories, does it?

Comment: @JasonNesbitt also, what I want is in the question. I want just something like `"All-Your-Base-00.jpg"`, without having to trim my response. Right now my response is like I posted in my question, `"<a href=\"All-Your-Base-00.jpg\"> All-Your-Base-00.jpg</a>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the captured group from the returned match. That is, you have:

```
var arr = regex.Matches(photosName).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

First, change that to:

```
var arr = regex.Matches(photosName).Cast<Match>();
```

You then want to go through each match:

```
foreach (Match m in arr)
{
    var name = m.Groups["name"].Value;
    // name now contains the captured group
}
```

Comment: Hey Jim. This gets me a error: `Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'` .

Comment: @user3838190: See my edit. You need to change the code so that you get a collection of `Match` objects rather than strings.

Comment: It worked! But now, the first match is a "Parent Directory." That I can solve. Thanks.